# SqlServer 2008 - Enable Net Named Pipes via command line

Tags: sql-server-2008, command-line, named-pipes

As part of our Integration build we are installing sql server 2008 on a machine then deploying various software on it. One piece of software requires that Net Named pipes is enabled for it to install.

As the server is built automatically as part of our continuous build process, we have to be able to do this via a non-interactive command line.

**Does anyone know of a way to enable the named pipes within the "Sql Server Network Configuration" section without a gui? (I.e. Command line only)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the protocol information is stored in the registry at :

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib`

There is also a powershell for Sql Server that is called `sqlps.exe` that is in the Binn directory of Sql server. That also offers programatic access to the configuration.

In my case, importing a previously exported registry key for the net named pipes works just as I want it too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cli tool `sac` will do, what you need to do.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthewms/archive/2005/10/13/412453.aspx

See the `-N` option.

Comment: Turns out that the sac tool has been removed from sql server 2008.